# How do I select a line and put it into a variable (in jQuery)

Tags: jquery

In my code I show a 10 lines with a new salesorder on each line.
When the user click on one of the lines (= one of the sales order), I want to

1. take the salesorder (= get the selected value),
2. get more details about the sales order (=need to make select into my backend)
3. show the new details on a new page/view

My code looks like this:

```
    <div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="a">
    <li data-role="list-divider">Your Fav</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" data-dividertheme="c">
    <%
     loop at gt_fav_cust1 assigning <ls_fav_cust>.
    select single name1 into <ls_fav_cust>-custname
    from kna1 where kunnr = <ls_fav_cust>-kunnr.
    %>
    <li><a href="#customer" data-transition="flip" data-rel="dialog">
    <%= <ls_fav_cust>-kunnr %>
    <%= <ls_fav_cust>-custname %>
    </a></li>
    <%
    endloop.
    %>
    </ul>
```

Can anybody guide me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Aikon

Comment: Can you post the actual outputted HTML? It looks like you posted ASP code or something.

Comment: Seriously what language is that? That is some hardcore DB integration right there.

Comment: @Eykanal - what do you mean by outputted HTML?
This is my code for jQuery mixed with my values from my DB system (SAP).
It is BSP language, jQuery and SAP.
I should be able to use jQuery in code. The code between <% and %> is SAP code.

Comment: I don't know what SAP code is, but in order to provide a good answer, we'll need to see how the individual `<li>` elements look for each record. Providing that would allow us to help you a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to bind into the click of the anchors within the ul (or since you're using jQuery Mobile you could look at the "tap" event).

Within your callback on that bind you could do a preventDefault() and then use $.mobile.changePage() to get/post the selected info to your backend and transition to your new page where you can display the data.

[jQuery Mobile Methods](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/api/events.html#../../docs/api/methods.html)